# Can I debug inside a for or if in julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

would you please help me? if I have a code including some loops and IFs, how can I debug inside FOR or IF, line by line. 
for example 
I can use shift+enter for every line. but when it is used for a For all loop will run. Is there any facility to debug inside a loop line by line?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run line by line in e.g. Juno by just highlighting the line, that will not run the entire loop. I'd recommend doing that.
With regards to an actual debugger, there is not currently one available for julia-1.x. But there's Rebugger.jl, it's use is quite advanced though.